# Exception while property mapping at property path "":Property"propertyname"was not found in target object of type"In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User"

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have implemented the below given code to extend the femanager extension in my own custom extension.

**classes.php**:

```php
return [
    \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class => [
        'subclasses' => [
            \TYP\TypCfg\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::class
        ]
    ],
    \TYP\TypCfg\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::class => [
        'tableName' => 'fe_users',
        'recordType' => 0,
    ]
];
```

**ext_localconf.php**:

```php
GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
    ->registerImplementation(NewController::class, \TYP\TypCfg\Controller\NewController::class);
```

**FrontendUser.php**:

```php
<?php
namespace TYP\TypCfg\Domain\Model;
/**
 * Class FrontendUser
 * @package TYP\TypCfg\Domain\Model
 */
class FrontendUser extends \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User
{
    const TABLE_NAME = 'fe_users';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $propertyname = '';
    
    public function getPropertyname()
    {
        return $this->propertyname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $propertyname
     */
    public function setPropertyname($propertyname)
    {
        $this->propertyname = $propertyname;
    }

}
```

All the steps given in the link https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/main/en-us/Features/NewFields/Index.html are performed properly. But still I am facing this error. How can I solve this?

Comment: 1. Where is TCA? 2. Specify full path 3. place controller code. Which action you want to extend? edit your requirement.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version and femanager version do you use?

Comment: I am using typo3 version 11.5.19 and femanager's early access version. i.e. 7.1.0

Answer (score 2):

If you are using v7.1 of femanager in TYPO3 11 or 12 you have to add this to your extensions /Configuration/Services.yaml

```yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User: '@TYP\TypCfg\Domain\Model\FrontendUser'
```

Comment: Can we override controller with the same way? e.g: `TER\ExtNameController\MapController: '@TYPO3\ExtName\Controller\CustomController'`. I tried this way, but not working properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to owrride your domain like below in **ext_localconf.php** file.

```
//override default FEmanager controller

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class] = [
    'className' => \vendor\extensionName\Domain\Model\FeUser::class,
];
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
    ->registerImplementation(
        \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class,
        \vendor\extensionName\Domain\Model\FeUser::class
    );
```